# Cannot make two vertical lines stick to the bottom when scrolling the page

Tags: html, css, alignment, sticky

I'm trying to create a website that has two vertical lines on each side. Even when the user scrolls up and down the page, I want the lines to stick to always stick to the bottom. For some reason, one lines always sticks to the bottom, while other line only sticks to the bottom when scrolling to the bottom.

This is what I have:

[image]

I believe this has to do with display element, but after trying everything and searching online resources, I cannot find the solution.

Here's the snippet code relevant to this issue (I won't post the entire code since it's irrelevant and long:

HTML

```
    <div id = "sticky-line-right">
        <p id = "right-para">ABCD@gmail.com</p>
        <div id = "right-line"></div>
    </div>

    <div id = "sticky-line-left">
        <a href = "https://www.google.ca" id = "github">
            <img src = "photos/github.png" alt = "Jason's Github page" width = "20px" height = "20px">
        </a>
        
        <a href = "https://www.google.ca" id = "linkedin">
            <img src = "photos/linkedin.png" alt = "Jason's Linkedin page" width = "20px" height = "20px">
        </a>
        
        <div id = "left-line"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#sticky-line-left {
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    margin-left: 5%;
    display: block;
}

#sticky-line-right {
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    margin-right: 5%;
    display: block;
}

#github {
    margin-left: -8px;
    display: block;
}

#linkedin {
    margin-left: -8px;
    display: block;
}

#left-line {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    height: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: block;
}

#right-line {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    height: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I got the question wrong but use `position: fixed;`, if you want it to remain fixed in bottom. Why use `position: sticky;`